# In an array of arrays how do I multiply each value by a different multiplier

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, arr

```
var arrayOfArrays = [
    [1,2,3,4,5], /* row a */
    [1,2,3,4,5], /* row b */
    [1,2,3,4,5], /* row c */
    [1,2,3,4,5], /* row d */
    [1,2,3,4,5] /* row e */
];

for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfArrays.length; i++) {
  var outterArr = arrayOfArrays[i];
  for (var x = 0; x < outterArr.length; x++) {
    var innerArr = arrayOfArrays[x];
    console.log(innerArr[x]);
  console.log('******************');
  }
}
```

As you can see above, I've got a multi-dimensional array.

I'm trying to loop through the array, and multiply each value according to the row they are in:

- Row A multiply by 10
- Row A multiply by 20
- Row A multiply by 30
- Row A multiply by 40
- Row A multiply by 50

So far in the above code I've managed to loop through the outer array, loop through the inner array and print the values delimitated by ******************.

I'm wondering what would be the best way to multiply the values by the different row multiplier and log each result on one line, spaced by ******************.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for the comments everyone! You're all amazing!

It seems like most comments took advantage of the fact that the multipliers happen to be multiples of 10.

How would the answers change if the multipliers were unique:

- Row A multiply by 21
- Row A multiply by 45
- Row A multiply by 56
- Row A multiply by 67
- Row A multiply by 87

Comment: do you need just to multiply or to store the result?

Comment: multiply and log the results spaced by *********** - in a similar fashion to how i've logged the inner array values

Comment: Did you mean to put all row A in your example of what to multiply by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run forEach on the array and multiply based on the index:

```js
var arrayOfArrays = [
    [1,2,3,4,5], /* row a */
    [1,2,3,4,5], /* row b */
    [1,2,3,4,5], /* row c */
    [1,2,3,4,5], /* row d */
    [1,2,3,4,5] /* row e */
];

arrayOfArrays.forEach((a, i) => {
  let mult = ((i + 1) * 10)
  a.forEach((num) => {
    num = num * mult
    console.log(num)
    console.log('******************');
  })
})
```

Comment: What if I was to ignore that the multipliers just happen to be multiples of 10; lets say the multipliers were: 21,45,56,67,87;

Comment: Because you already have three answers to this question, you may have more luck and be more within the community guidelines by posting this as a new question.

Comment: Thanks, I will do. 

Answer (score 1):

Take the values from `outterArr[x]`, because `outterArr` is the row.

```js
var arrayOfArrays = [
    [1,2,3,4,5], /* row a */
    [1,2,3,4,5], /* row b */
    [1,2,3,4,5], /* row c */
    [1,2,3,4,5], /* row d */
    [1,2,3,4,5]  /* row e */
];

for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfArrays.length; i++) {
    var outterArr = arrayOfArrays[i];
    for (var x = 0; x < outterArr.length; x++) {
        var innerVal = outterArr[x];          // change this to outterArr[x]
        //             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
        console.log(innerVal * (i + 1) * 10); // multiply value 
        console.log('******************');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the shortest possible answer:

```js
var arrayOfArrays = [
    [1,2,3,4,5], /* row a */
    [1,2,3,4,5], /* row b */
    [1,2,3,4,5], /* row c */
    [1,2,3,4,5], /* row d */
    [1,2,3,4,5] /* row e */
];

var newArr = arrayOfArrays.map( (v,i) => v.map( x=> x *= (i+1) * 10 ) );

console.log(newArr);
```

The body of arrow function only needs to be enclosed by { .. } if there’s more than one expression, or if the body consists of a non-expression statement. If there’s only one expression, and you omit the surrounding { .. } , there’s an implied return in front of the expression, as illustrated in the previous snippet.

Comment: Might be shortest but from a beginners perspective this is most likely completely confusing

Comment: That is true but I love ES6  - I simply couldn't resist